# Extract extensionless files using Phar

Tags: php, phar

Using PHPs [Phar](http://php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php), how can I specify which type of file I have, when it does not have and extension?

I have a directory of files with randomly generated names, all files are *tar.gz* and have the same structure, I want to extract only a single file, config.xml:

Using:

```
$phar = new PharData($source_file);
$phar->extractTo($tmp, 'config.xml');
```

I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: Cannot create phar '/path/to/fkd20c3nd', file extension (or combination) not recognised or the directory does not exist in /path/to/my_script.php:123

However, this is only because the file is randomly named on disk, i.e.

```
fkd20c3nd
```

If I just rename this to

```
fkd20c3nd.tar.gz
```

Phar works just fine.

**Question being**

How can I use Phar to extract a file that is missing the extension, besides making a copy of it first, with a new name? Can I simply tell Phar the file type?

Answer (score 1):

`.phar` file names need to contain at least a dot in the middle of its name so that the file name.

The technical reason for this is that you can access files inside a phar by passing its combined path like "/path/to/my.phar/README.rst", and without a dot it would not work.
I know in your case you don't need this, but the same internal functions are used to detect the correctness of a phar name.